# When Clicking a Row in Table Builder, SlideOver Does Not Open as Expected

Tags: laravel, filamentphp

When using Table Builder, I encounter an issue where, upon clicking a row, the intended SlideOver does not open as expected.

I followed the instructions provided at
https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/tables/advanced#record-urls-clickable-rows

```
use Filament\Tables\Table;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
public function table(Table $table): Table
{
    return $table
        ->recordUrl(
            fn (Model $record): string => route('posts.edit', ['record' => $record]),
        );
}
```

But instead of opening the SlideOver, the infolist opens on a new page.

When I add 'slideOver()' to a button placed on the table from the actions section, it opens in SlideOver without any issues.

The problem arises specifically when attempting to open SlideOver by clicking on a row.

Any guidance on resolving this issue would be appreciated